# Хэш-таблицы: откуда берется ключ объекта memcache

Tags: хеширование, memcached

Объясните чайнику, откуда берется ключ объекта memcache?

Я, вроде бы, осилила скрипт, который будет помещать в memcache определенный статичный код (в тот самый объект).
Но не могу понять, каким образом этому объекту присваивается ключ при сохранении  его в memcache?

Насколько я понимаю, какие-то аналогии с автоинкрементом тут не подходят.

Объясните, пожалуйста, для "тупых" - самыми простыми словами.
Спасибо!

Comment: На самом деле вам виднее откуда его брать. За вас этого никто не скажет. Вы сохраняете в кеше некие данные и хотите что бы потом их можно было достать от туда, когда они понадобятся. Тогда вам надо ответить на вопрос: "какими данными располагает запрашивающий информацию из кеша в момент запроса". Ключ строиться вот как раз из того, что вам известно когда хотите получить значение из кеша. И это может быть что угодно: id сущности где то еще, название страницы, md5 от содержимого (правда откуда бы запрашивающему знать этот md5)

Comment: Спасибо, Mike. Можно ли в качестве этого ключа использовать  basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) ??

Comment: Да, вполне, если у вас используется перезапись (в .htaccess) и последним компонентом переданного url является не имя вашего .php файла

Comment: Я как раз хотела использовать имя файла.

Comment: Я просто почему то подумал, что файл у вас всего один. А если у вас их много и тот код что с кешем в них включается, то да, можно их использовать конечно.